# adding user to docker container and give them access to host folder

Tags: dockerfile

I am able only to give the first user write, executable and read access to the `export` folder in the below `Dockerfile`

```
...
VOLUME ["/export/"]    

RUN groupadd galaxy \
&& chgrp -R galaxy /export \
&& chmod -R 770 /export

RUN useradd dudleyk \
    && mkdir /home/dudleyk \
    && chown dudleyk:dudleyk /home/dudleyk \
    && addgroup dudleyk galaxy \    
    && ln -s /export/ /home/dudleyk/ \
    && echo "dudleyk:dudleyk" | chpasswd 

RUN useradd lorencm \
    && mkdir /home/lorencm \
    && chown lorencm:lorencm /home/lorencm \
    && addgroup lorencm galaxy \
    && ln -s /export/ /home/lorencm/ \
    && echo "lorencm:lorencm" | chpasswd 


EXPOSE 8787

CMD ["/init"]
```

I logged to the docker container with `docker run -it -v /home/galaxy:/export rstudio bash` and it showed me the following

```
ls -ahl
drwxr-xr-x  43 dudleyk galaxy 4.0K Apr  8 00:09 export
```

How do I give the second user write, executable and read access to the `export`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the output of performing 'whoami' in your container?

Comment: I logged as the user lorencm in Rstudio-server, but I could get any write permission. However, dudleyk has write permission.